# Select single row with LINQ TO SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I start deal with LINQ To SQL and I try solve this primitive problem.
I have very simple table with two columns.

- Nick - key, unique
- Password

I would like delete row with some nick value.

I use this method:

```
    public void DeleteSpiritUser(string nick)
    {
        var user = from u in _dc.Spirit_Users where u.Nick == nick select u;

        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            _dc.Spirit_Users.DeleteOnSubmit(user.First());

            try
            {
                _dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Problem is that I must use user.First() if I want one single row, I would like select with LINQ only one row know IEnumerable, because Nick is unique.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this - just select only the first (if present), and only delete if you got a value:

```
public void DeleteSpiritUser(string nick)
{
    var user = (from u in _dc.Spirit_Users 
                where u.Nick == nick 
                select u).SingleOrDefault();

    if(user != null)
    {
       using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
       {
           _dc.Spirit_Users.DeleteOnSubmit(user);
           _dc.SubmitChanges();
           scope.Complete();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why did you put the try-catch since the scope is already declared with the using block and the transaction will be aborted if the complete method is not called?

Comment: @Davide Piras: the original question had that already - I just copied it. But I agree - this is a bit off - either catch and **handle** the exception, or then just let it happen and bubble up....

Comment: @Davide Piras: fixed my answer - this makes more sense! If an exception happens, the caller needs to deal with it

Comment: You might want to consider SingleOrDefault instead of FirstOrDefault if that nick must be unique: Single(OrDefault) gives an error if there are two "nicks", First(OrDefault) silently ignores a duplicate.

Comment: @Hans Kesting: yes, that's true - using `SingleOrDefault` would also cause an exception if more than one row was found (which should never happen anyway, if `nick` is really unique)

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
var user = _dc.Spirit_Users.Single(u => u.Nick == nick);
```

Comment: Then you should put this call inside the try....catch since it'll bomb out when no match for `nick` is found

Comment: Or use SingleOrDefault, which returns a null (or rather the default value) if nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

Well First() is the one that will extract the first (and only) row (plus it will add TOP 1 to query). Linq2Sql doesn't know that you only have one row (or that you'll have any at all) and is preparing to receive more than one, thus IEnmuerable even when there is one row.